# Apache as proxy does not display images?

Tags: apache, proxy

I use Play framework and Apache as proxy.

My Play app runs at port: 9000

My Apache runs at portt: 9999

I config the Apache to serve as proxy as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:9999>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass  /excluded !

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works fine.
However, when I add images to Apache root folder like this:

htdocs/a_folder/pic.jpg

Then, in my Play app, I load the image like this:

http://localhost:9999/a_folder/pic.jpg

The image does not get displayed and the request on the browser run forever.
How can I config the Apache to load static images (and might be other resources)?

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the static assets with an /excluded/ prefix and set an Alias for /excluded/ that points to your existing documentroot.  Otherwise, exclude /a_folder/ the same way /excluded is in line 4 of your code block.